# Intersection of intersections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Having the following schema:

`(A {id})-[:C]->(B)`

I need to:

1. (A{id:1}) ∩ (A{id:2}) ∩ (A{id:3}) => G1
2. (A{id:4}) ∩ (A{id:5}) ∩ (A{id:6}) => G2
3. G1 ∩ G2

The third step is not a problem but I'm having problems with step 1 and 2 since the groups could be formed by up to 30 elements of type A and

```
MATCH (v:A{id: 1})-[:C]->(b:B)<-[:C]-(as:A) 
WHERE as.id in [1,2,3]
RETURN count(distinct b)
```

generates the union not the intersection. Could this problem be done with one query?

EDIT: on step one I save the result of the first intersection on G1 and the result of the second intersection on G2.  The third step uses these two sets of data

Comment: I can't quite see the correlation between the operations in 1 and 2 above and the query you cited below. Also, if id is a unique identifier to :A nodes, then `count(distinct v)` will always get you 1. Could you clarify exactly what you want the query to do in full?

Comment: Sorry,  posted wrong query.  I hope that now it is more clarified.  Basically two sets are obtained from the intersections and the third step is to intersect these sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out this neo4j knowledge base article on [performing match intersection](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/).

There are several ways to do this in the article. Applying the first approach to your problem, this would give you the intersection of :B nodes reachable by all the :A nodes in the collection:

```
WITH [1,2,3] as ids
MATCH (a:A)-[:C]->(b:B)
WHERE a.id in ids
WITH b, size(ids) as inputCnt, count(DISTINCT a) as cnt
WHERE cnt = inputCnt
RETURN b
```